# Wpf Sliding Stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

Hi i have a stack panel with buttons. Lets say "||" represents the stackpanel and "o" represents a button which the user can see and "x" represents a button which the user cant see due to the window dimensions.

Note: The windows dimension is such a way that I can only see 3 buttons at any point of time.

1234567
|xxoooxx|
Above, i have 7 buttons added to the stackpanel. 3 of which are IN VIEW "O" and 4 of which are not in view "X".

**

- The behaviour i want

**
As the user moves his mouse over the right side of the WINDOW, i want the stack panel to accelerate to the left becoming:
 1234567
|xxxxooo|

Likewise if the user moves his mouse to the left side of the WINDOW, i want the stack pael to accelrate to the right becoming
 1234567
|oooxxxx|

If the user has his mouse near the center of the window, the stackpanel should not move.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You obviously need a MouseMove event then you need to hook it to your stack panel.

Answer (score 0):

Given the same requirement I would use a list box(set stack panel orientation to horizontal). so its a list box of buttons.

And then write mouse move event on the list box, based on the delta of mouse movement I would re arrange my buttons in the list box.

Hope this helps.